# How to verify method was reached if throw before

Tags: c#, nunit

I have my method as below which `adds new user to database` when such `user name` doesn't exist in database. If `user name` exist it `throws custom exception` therefore `addUserType` method is not reached.

```
public void CreateUserType(UserType userType)
{
    if (userType == null) throw new ApplicationException("UserType object cannot be null");

    if (_bottleClientQuery.IsUserTypeExist(userType.Name)) throw new ApplicationException("Such user type name already exist");
    _bottleClientRepository.AddUserType(userType);
}
```

My testing methods are as shown below:

This method correctly giving me the expected result:

```
[Test]
public void CreateUserType_UserTypeExists_ThrowsApplicationException()
{
       UserQuery.Setup(uow => uow.IsUserTypeExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

       Assert.Throws<Exceptions.ApplicationException>(() => CreateClientService.CreateUserType(new UserType()));
}
```

Nevertheless in this method i want to check whether `AddUserType was reached` or not. I `setup` it as `IsUserTypeExist returns true` which means such `user name exist` therefore 
 `AddUserType` will be not reached.

```
[Test]
public void CreateUserType_UserTypeExists_AddUserTypeRepositoryNotReached()
{
       UserQuery.Setup(uow => uow.IsUserTypeExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

        CreateClientService.CreateUserType(new UserType());

        UserRepository.Verify(uow => uow.AddUserType(It.IsAny<UserType>()),Times.Never);
}
```

The problem with second test method is the `ApplicationException` is `thrown` (that's fully fine and expected) but i would really like to test whether `AddUserType` was `not reached`.

Is it possible when before thrown exception was there?

Comment: catch the exception and assert your expected behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your test method to something like this;

```
[Test]
public void CreateUserType_UserTypeExists_AddUserTypeRepositoryNotReached()
{
    UserQuery.Setup(uow => uow.IsUserTypeExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

    Assert.Throws<ApplicationException>(() => CreateClientService.CreateUserType(new UserType()));

    UserRepository.Verify(uow => uow.AddUserType(It.IsAny<UserType>()),Times.Never);
}
```

This will both verify that the expected exception is thrown and ensure that execution continues to your next verification.